# iPhone "software" vs. "hardware" keyboard layout?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm a bit confused. In the keyboard settings of my iPhone are two options:
"sofware keyboard layout" and "hardware keyboard layout"

But what is the latter? Isn't they keyboard totally "software"? What does it mean?
And why do I need it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With iOS 4 and above, you can pair a Bluetooth keyboard to the phone. That's the hardware keyboard for which you'd be specifying the layout.